# Update column with another column value of different row in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table where I am storing properties for entries.

- Id - Foreign key. Points out to the actual entry in another table.
- Key - The key of the property.
- Value - The value of the property.

Current table structure:

| id | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | property1 | value11 |
| 1 | oldvalue | oValue1 |
| 1 | newvalue | nValue1 |
| 2 | property1 | value12 |
| 2 | oldvalue | oValue2 |
| 2 | newvalue | nValue2 |
| 3 | property1 | value13 |
| 3 | oldvalue | oValue3 |
| 3 | newvalue | nValue3 |

I newly added the column `Previous Value` and I want to store properties' old value and new value in a single row instead of two. Thus, I will need to copy the value of the "oldvalue" key into the new column of same id, and rename the "newvalue" key to just "value". Also this needs to be done iteratively for all the id's where the oldvalue property-value is present.

Target table structure:

| id | Key | Value | Previous Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | property1 | value11 | null |
| 1 | value | nValue1 | oValue1 |
| 2 | property1 | value12 | null |
| 2 | value | nValue2 | oValue2 |
| 3 | property1 | value13 | null |
| 3 | value | nValue3 | oValue3 |

So basically, for each **ID**, if the key-value for "`oldvalue`" key is present, then copy the value of the property "`oldvalue`" to `Previous Value` column of the key "`newvalue`" for the same ID. Then rename all "`newvalue`" key to the new "`value`" only.

The above target table structure is what I need at the end after adding the column "Previous Value".

I have written an SQL Query for SQL Server and it is working:

```
update t1 set t1.previous_value = t2.value
from PROPERTIES_TABLE t1,
     PROPERTIES_TABLE t2
where t1.id = t2.id
  AND t1.key = 'newvalue'
and t2.key = 'oldvalue';


update PROPERTIES_TABLE
set key = 'value'
where key = 'newvalue';
```

But the query is not working since aliases does not work in PostgreSQL.

Comment: FYI, it's 2023, the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for *over 30 years*; there is no reason to be using the ANSI-89 implicit JOIN syntax anymore. Many of the features of the old implicit join syntax aren't even supported in recent versions of (R)DBMS. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: I must admit, as well, a column called `id` that isn't unique isn't really much of an identifier; identifiers are normally unique in nature.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL the target table of an UPDATE should **not** be repeated in the FROM clause.

```
update PROPERTIES_TABLE t1 
  set t1.previous_value = t2.value
from PROPERTIES_TABLE t2
where t1.id = t2.id
  AND t1.key = 'newvalue'
and t2.key = 'oldvalue';
```